# What does this error message mean? "Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: recordHistory"

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been receiving e-mails from Google Apps Script for some time now, even though I've never used Google Apps script, I didn't even know it existed.

The mail in question:

"The execution of your script, recordHistory, recently failed. A summary of the failures is provided below. To configure triggers for this script or modify your settings to receive future failure notifications

Function: recordHistory
Error message: You must be authorized to perform this action.
Trigger: time-based"

What could be the problem?

When I click on the link indicated in the e-mail, I'm sent back to "my triggers" on Google apps script with the identifier of the trigger in question in the filters, but it's not displayed in "my triggers", and the "my executions" page is also empty.

I don't understand where this is coming from and whether it's serious.

Comment: Before dealing with this error, I guess you first need to locate the script. Addon maybe?

Comment: Have you recorded a macro?

Comment: @Cooper Today, yes. But before I didn't have any macros and I still got this error message.

Comment: @WaximCorp Adding a module to Google form create scripts on Google apps script ?

I remember adding a module from the Google Wordspace Marketplace for a form on Google form, but I deleted it.